# BLDC motor position control

Tags: motor, dc, control, brushless-dc-motor, position

For my project, I need to control position and speed of a BLDC motor with PID. Although there is information about the speed control of the motor, I could not find much information about the position control. How can I position a BLDC?

Can I check the position of brushless motors produced for helicopters and drones? I couldn't find the motor model either, can you suggest an engine model?

Comment: Motors with encoders exists. Could that be an option for you? For what purpose do you need position control?

Comment: Stepper motors are better for position control. However, if you need to use BLDC and control the position and motion, you can check out this write-up. It may help: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/support/videos/ball-toss-case-study.html

Comment: There are DC motors with encoders, but I want the response time to be short for stabilization. I need position control for the gimbal platform. Can I provide stabilization with a DC motor with encoder?